# Intermediate to Advanced level Counting Problem

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we fill a 3 by 3 grid with 0s and/or 1s, so that every row and every column has an odd total?

Answer (score 2):

Classify according to the top row:

If the top row has 1's then each columm can either have the bottom two cells with all 0's or all 1's. It is easy to see there are $4$ cases

If the top left has a $1$ and the rest in the top have $0$ proceed to classify on the left column, if it has all 1's then it is easy to see there are 2 cases. If the left column has 1 at the top and the rest are $0$ then there are  $2$ cases. So in this case there are $4$ grids.

If the top right has a $1$ and the rest $0$ by symmetry with the last case there are also $4$ grids.

If the top center has a $1$ and the rest are $0$ classify on the center column, if it is all 1's then there are 2 cases. If the center column has $1$ on the top and zero everywhere else then are also $2$ cases.

So in total there are $4+4+4+4=16$ cases.